# How can I download the page source from the website directly?

Tags: web

Someone asked me to do a few changes on their business website but they don't have the source code and they don't remember who developed website to ask from him. Is there a way I can clone the website(Download the source code) and do the changes then publish it with a new domain and server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Front-end code is available directly in the browser. If it's a single-page site, you can literally right-click > Save As > Webpage, Complete to download all the relevant files. If it's a multi-page site, you can use a web scrapper (e.g. [Beautiful Soup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) to programmatically crawl and download each page.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible, but very complicated. Probably some backend code or minified code is used. In this case, it's (nearly) impossible to download and change the site.

I would recommend to recreate the page with modern tools like webflow (graphical website builder) or astro (powerful framework for content-rich sites).

When it's a small site without backend, you can try hitting `Ctrl + S`.